# I get 'canvas object has no attribute get_tk_widget' error in the tkinter

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, syntax-error

When I run the following codes in the thinkter library, I get an attribute error from get_tk_widget().I get 'canvas object has no attribute get_tk_widget' error. What can I write instead of this code?

---

```
try:
        if canvas:
            canvas.get_tk_widget().grid_forget()
```

```
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
        canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
        canvas_widget.grid(row=8, columnspan=4, sticky="nsew")
```

```
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas_widget.get_tk_widget().xview)
        scrollbar.grid(row=9, columnspan=4, sticky="ew")
        canvas_widget.get_tk_widget().configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

```
canvas_widget.get_tk_widget().bind('<Configure>', on_canvas_configure)
```

The Gui screen opens, but the get_tk_widget here gives the attirbute error.

Answer (score 2):

`canvas_widget` is an instance of `tkinter.Canvas` widget, so it does not have `get_tk_widget()` function.

You need to change those `canvas_widget.get_tk_widget()` to `canvas_widget`:

```py
...
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas_widget.xview)
scrollbar.grid(row=9, columnspan=4, sticky="ew")
canvas_widget.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
...
canvas_widget.bind("<Configure>", on_canvas_configure)
```

Comment: When I do as you say, I cannot see the graphics on the gui screen. blank screen comes

Comment: @HüseyinCENİK How can we know why you get a blank screen with just a few lines of provided code? It is better to provide a [mre].